# How to find orthonormal basis of the vector subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find an orthonormal basis of the subspace V of the space IR4 with the usual inner product, generated by the vectors (4,−2,1,−3),(5,−3,2,−4),(−2,0,1,1)

It's well done? I want to know if the calculations are correct
$ v_1 =(4,-2,1,-3) v_2=(5,-3,2,-4) v_3= (-2,0,1,1)$
$u_1 = (4,-2,1,-3)$
$ u_2 = v_2. - \frac{v_2 .u_1}{u_1 . u_1}u_1$
$ u_2= (5,-3,2,-4)-\frac{(5,-3,2,-4)(4,−2,1,−3)}{(4,−2,1,−3)(4,−2,1,−3)}(4,−2,1,−3) $
$u_2= (5,-3,2,-4) - \frac{40}{30}(4,−2,1,−3)$
$u_2 = (5,-3,2,-4)- \frac{4}{3}(4,−2,1,−3)$
$u_2 = (\frac{-1}{3}, \frac{-1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{-8}{3})$

$u_2= 3(\frac{-1}{3}, \frac{-1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{-8}{3})$

$u_2= (-1,-1,2,-8)$
$u_3= v_3 - \frac{v_3 . u_1)}{u_1 .u_1}u_1 - \frac{v_3 . u_2}{u_2 . u_2}u_2$

$u_3=  (-2,0,1,1)- \frac{ (-2,0,1,1) . (4,-2,1,-3)}{(4,-2,1,-3).(4,-2,1,-3)} u_1 - \frac{(-2,0,1,1) . (-1,-1,2,-8)}{(-1,-1,2,-8).(-1,-1,2,-8)}$

$ u_3= (-2,0,1,1) - ( \frac {-10}{40})(4,-2,1,-3) - \frac{4}{58}$

$u_3=(-2,0,1,1) - ( \frac{-1}{4}) . (4,-2,1,-3) - \frac{2}{29}(-1,-1,2,-8)$
$u_3 = (-2,0,1,1)-(-1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{-1}{4}, \frac{3}{4})- (\frac{-2}{29},\frac{-2}{29}, \frac{4}{29}, \frac{-16}{29})$

$u_3=  (-2,0,1,1) - (-1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{-1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}) - (-2,-2,4,16)$
$u_3 =(-2,0,1,1) -(3,\frac{5}{2},\frac{17}{4},\frac{-61}{4})$

$u_3 = (1,\frac{-5}{2}, \frac{-13}{4},\frac{65}{4})$

Comment: have you checked if the vectors that span the subspace are linearly independent? if they are just use the Gram-Schmidt process like you did.

Comment: They tell me that I must first use the Gram-Schmidt process, I want to know if the calculations have been done correctly, then we orthonormalize dividing each vector by its norm. can you verify my calculations?

Comment: "Orthonormal" means that the vectors are all orthogonal - perpendicular - to each other, *and are all normal*, that is, of unit length. You've worked for the first property, and you can check that by simply calculating all the $u_i \cdot u_j$ inner products to see if they are all $0$. But, you've completely ignored the second requirement.